# How c# toggles div styles with button clicks

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

My question is: the first time I click the button, div is displayed; But a subsequent click stays in this state, and display does not convert to none.

In LiB.aspx I created a button, and a div. I want to make div appear by clicking the button; When clicked again, this div can dispaly to none (the default). These two steps can be repeated as a cycle.
The code for.aspx is shown below.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="moreLimits" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

```
<div id="child1" class="childl" style="display: none;" runat="server"></div>
```

The code related to the.aspx.cs file is as follows.

```
bool bShow = true;
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (bShow)
        {
            Button1.Text = "cancelLimits";
            child1.Style.Value = "display:block";
            bShow = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Button1.Text = "moreLimits";
            child1.Style.Value = "display:none";
            bShow = true;
        }

    }
```

My suspicion is that bShow has not been changed to false. But I'm not sure how to solve it, or is there another correct way to write it.
Many thanks to the people who can solve this problem and give help!

Comment: Every time the page loads, the field `bShow` is initialised to `true`. What you want to do is look at the current state of the button itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many ways, this is a good question!

The first day, the first thing, the first lesson in web development?

It is what we call state-less.

By the term state-less, I mean EACH time your web page (that is sitting on the user's desktop) is just a web page. On the server side?

You don't have a computer for each user like you do on the desktop. You have ONE computer - that ONE web server.

Anyone of 10 users can click on that button (say an imaginary 10 users).

So, what is the state of that bShow?

Answer:

That code behind for that page?

it starts from scratch EACH time!!

You MUST grasp the concept of a so called "round-trip" or post-back in web land.

The way this works is you have this:

[image]

Note VERY, but BEYOND close, note how I do NOT have the page showing on the right side (on the server).

The web server is waiting to process ANY page, from ANY of your users  - not JUST you!!!

You do NOT have this:

Note how your page class - code behind is NOT in memory on the server.

YOU DO NOT have this:

NOTE VERY careful here - the web page is ON CLIENT computer - it is NOT existing at all on the web server side.

[image]

And you DO NOT EVEN have this:

[image]

So, now you click your button, the web page is SENT to the web server.

This:

[image]

So NOW your page is sitting on the server.

NOW a instance of the page class is created, and your code behind starts running.

Your code behind can modify controls (even controls to be visible or not), but the page is NOT interacting with the user - ONLY code can MODIFY the web page. So, one change, or MANY changes to the web page can occur, but AS YOU update things like a text box etc., the user does NOT see these changes just yet. So, you can't say run a loop to flash a text box on and off - since the changes are occurring on the server - the client side browser does not have the web page any more!

It is THEN sent back to the client side, and the server side class instance and code is TOSSED OUT - DOES NOT exist!!! Your server side page class is disposed - removed from memory, and the web page code behind does NOT exist any more.

So, page travels back to the client side, is re-displayed, JavaScript is loaded, and THEN JavaScript starts running.

[image]

Note how I do NOT show the page on the right side.

On the server? Once the page is sent back to the user?

On server side, the page (and code variables) are disposed, removed, and DO NOT exist any more. The web server is now ready FOR ANY OTHER user to post back THEIR page.

So, your code behind (the page class) is state-less. The variables in the code behind START OVER each time. (in fact all fo the code does!).

Thus, you can't set some value at the "base" level of the page class like you have, since that page DOES NOT remain in memory!

it ONLY exists during the "round trip", and ONLY during the time that the page is up on the server. Once all of your code (not just some, but ALL code is done running?

The page THEN travels back to the client side. The web page is reloaded, re-drawn, and JavaScript etc on that page STARTS over also!!!

(you can think of the client side JavaScript code in the browser VERY much like the server in reverse!!! - its variables (client side) ALSO now are re-set!!!).

So, how to deal with this issue?

Well, there are several "common" approaches.

retain the variable value in Session[].

Session is a server side "thing" that allows you to shove some values into, and they remain and "persist" on the server - EVEN when the web page is disposed (which I stated occurs EVERY time the page travels back to the user).

So, session is one such way.

Another way?

You can use what is called ViewState.

Viewstate is "similar" to session, but it is not global to the "one" user, but only to the current web page.

So, session() can be used to pass values to another page, ViewState cannot.

And ViewState is browser based (it in EACH browser page), where as session() is per user (server side).

And another common way?

You can use a hidden textbox, or even a control called "hiddenField". This is control on the web page, and you can check the value of the control.

And another way?

place the value into the URL, or so called "url query parameter".

So, lots of ways to do this.

Let's do this two ways:

First example, we will use session:

So, our code becomes this:

```
    bool bShow = true;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            bShow = true;
            Session["MyShow"] = bShow;
        }
        else
        {
            // restore state of bShow
            bShow = (bool)["MyShow"];
        }
    }

    protected void cmdTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (bShow)
        {
            Button1.Text = "cancelLimits";
            child1.Style.Value = "display:block";
            bShow = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Button1.Text = "moreLimits";
            child1.Style.Value = "display:none";
            bShow = true;
        }
    }
```

So, we place the value of our "variable" that is now persisted server side. Note that session is "per user", but global to all your code.

User browser state:

As noted, things like text boxes etc.? If they have a runat=server tag, then in most cases (not all), then the control state is persisted. I should point out that with plain HTML markup, such values are NOT persisted, but the state of the control(s) with runat=server in "most" cases are persisted.

So, we could use the state of the control.

And thus do this:

So, dump the use of bShow (since we now know it does NOT persist), and we could do this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (child1.Style["display"] == "block")
        {
            child1.Style.Add("display","none");
        }
        else
        {
            child1.Style.Add("display", "block");
        }
    }
```

And in fact, we could even do this:

(use visible in place of style).

```
        <div id="child1" class="childl" visible="false" runat="server">
            <h3>this is our div</h3>
        </div>
```

and then:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        child1.Visible = !child1.Visible;
    }
```

Note MUCH caution with the above example. If you set a control visible = false, then the control is NEVER sent to the browser side (after the page round trip). This can be VERY useful, but it also THEN means client side JavaScript code can't hide/show the control, since the control is NOT sent nor rendered to the client side.

Speaking of client side code?

One could write the code to hide/show the "div" 100% in client side code, and no post-back, and no round trip would be required.

So, this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="moreLimits" 
            OnClientClick="myhideshow();return false;"/>
        <br />
        <script>
            function myhideshow() {
                var mydiv = document.getElementById("child1")
                if (mydiv.style.display == 'none') {
                    mydiv.style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    mydiv.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        </script>
        <br />
        <div id="child1" class="childl" style="display:none" runat="server">
            <h3>this is our div</h3>
        </div>
```

And with above, note how the browser "spinner" shows no wait, since we are not making a round trip.

So, in web land?

The "big challenge" is that our code is state-less, and in fact every post-back is very much like starting from scratch each time.

As a result, you have to add to your "bag of tools" the concept of state.

Which type of state to use (ViewState, session(), control state) will VERY much define your NEW approach to writing code, and grasping how VERY much different web development is from desktop development.

The basic concept is that your page "class" and code starts from scratch EACH time a button or any post-back occures.

Often, today, a big goal to improve performance and give users a "desktop" like experience is we "consider" writing client side code in the browser (JavaScript), since then such operations do not require very expensive "round trips" which takes time, and slows down the operation of the page.

However, when starting out, often the above concepts are not all that solid in your development approach, and it is often a "pain" to write JavaScript code, but for many simple things, it is well worth the effort, since the you don't have to send the WHOLE page to the web server just to run a wee bit tiny of some code. So, often people attempt to push more and more code from the server side to the client side code, and thus your code and "many" operations can occur without that expensive post-back, or so called round trip.

So, the concept of round trip is required for any web development, and along with that concept is that term "state-less", since you page code (code behind) in effect starts from scratch EACH time any post-back occurs for any button. Once that server side code behind has run, and the page sent back to the user?

The page on the server side is dumped, disposed, and the web server is now ready to process ANY other web page any user sends to the web server - NOT just your page!!!

There is ONE computer and one web processor, and thus you don't have code + variables in memory for JUST the one user - the web server is multi-user, and thus common coding approaches used in desktop land will not work for web land.

### Edit

(Fix of bug - note ispostack check NEVER is required in button stub)

To fix a bug, I did not put BACK into session after messing around with bShow, so for the session example, the code should have been this:

```
    bool bShow = true;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            bShow = true;
            Session["MyShow"] = bShow;
        }
        else
        {
            // restore state of bShow
            bShow = (bool)Session["MyShow"];
        }
    }

    protected void cmdTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bShow = !bShow;


        if (bShow)
        {
            Button1.Text = "cancelLimits";
            child1.Style.Value = "display:block";
        }
        else
        {
            Button1.Text = "moreLimits";
            child1.Style.Value = "display:none";
        }
        Session["MyShow"] = bShow;
    }
```

Remember, if the session value is a OBJECT, then you do NOT have to shove back the value into session, since session becomes a pointer to the object, and no need to shove back into session again each time.

However, a bool var is not a object, so as per above, right after you change value of bShow, we have to put back into session.

However, if bshow was a object, then we DO NOT have to put back after changing!!!

So say this as object:

```
    public class mybol
    {
        public bool mytrue = true;
    }

    public mybol bShow = new mybol();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            bShow.mytrue = true;
            Session["MyShow"] = bShow;
        }
        else
        {
            // restore state of bShow
            bShow = (mybol)Session["MyShow"];
        }
    }

    protected void cmdTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bShow.mytrue = !bShow.mytrue;   // toggle state

        if (bShow.mytrue == true)
        {
            Button1.Text = "cancelLimits";
            child1.Style.Value = "display:block";
        }
        else
        {
            Button1.Text = "moreLimits";
            child1.Style.Value = "display:none";
        }
    }
```

Note VERY but VERY close in above? We don't have to shove back into session the value - since it is now a object.

However, in both cases, the "error" was that on our button click, we were NOT toggling the bShow value, but testing the state of the button, AND THEN doing a toggle!!! - that was a "error" in the posted logic. The last 2 code examples address this error in logic.

(It makes no sense to test the bShow true/false state, do some if/then, and THEN change the state of the bShow value. The button click MEANS to toggle the value so we toggle value AND THEN run the if/then logic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You give several methods, I have been debugging, found that the session code has a little problem. Maybe you accidentally missed some characters. So, add the modified code based on your scenario here.

Comment: ```bool bShow = false;protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){if (!IsPostBack){ bShow = false;Session["MyShow"] = bShow;}else{bShow = !(bool)Session["MyShow"];Session["MyShow"] = bShow;}}protected void cmdTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){if (bShow){Button1.Text = "lessLimits";child1.Style.Value = "display:block";}else{Button1.Text = "moreLimits";child1.Style.Value = "display:none";}}```

Comment: Actually, see the edit. (and by the way, do you actually think ANYONE can read that code mess in comments here?