# JS function vs C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, clientscriptmanager

I am quite new to JS and doing web apps and I am facing this problem:
I have JS code which creates me 6 gauges and function which updates gauge 1 value:

```
<!-- Include the Gauge.js library -->
<!-- Raphael must be included before justgage -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.4/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/justgage/1.2.9/justgage.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Initialize the gauge on page load -->
    <script>
        var gauge1;
        var gauge2;
        var gauge3;
        var gauge4;
        var gauge5;
        var gauge6;

        function updateGaugeValue(newValue, event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            gauge1.refresh(newValue);
        }

        window.onload = function () {

            gauge1 = new JustGage({
                id: "gauge1",
                value: 0,
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                title: "My Gauge",
                label: "Value"
            });

            gauge2 = new JustGage({
                id: "gauge2",
                value: 0,
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                title: "My Gauge",
                label: "Value"
            });

            gauge3 = new JustGage({
                id: "gauge3",
                value: 0,
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                title: "My Gauge",
                label: "Value"
            });

            gauge4 = new JustGage({
                id: "gauge4",
                value: 0,
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                title: "My Gauge",
                label: "Value"
            });

            gauge5 = new JustGage({
                id: "gauge5",
                value: 0,
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                title: "My Gauge",
                label: "Value"
            });

            gauge6 = new JustGage({
                id: "gauge6",
                value: 0,
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                title: "My Gauge",
                label: "Value"
            });

        };

</script>
```

When I call update from button like this

```
<button onclick="updateGaugeValue(5, event)">Click me</button>
```

function normally works and change value of gauge 1 to 5.
But when I try to call this function from C# (using ASP.NET) via ClientScript like:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "updateGaugeValue(5, event)", true);
```

nothing happens. But if I try to test it and alert hello world like

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "alert('Hello World')", true);
```

it normally works and alert. Any suggestions? I expect that I am able to call this JS function from C# code.

Comment: There is no `event` when you call `"updateGaugeValue(5, event)"` by registering it as a startup script.

Comment: Just check if `event` exists before calling `preventDefault()` (i.e., `if (event) { event.preventDefault(); }`). Then, in your `RegisterStartupScript` call, just call the function without `event` (i.e., `"updateGaugeValue(5)"`).

Comment: I tried, from button works normally, but from c# again not

Comment: What does the console say? In browser dev tools. Hitting F12 in your browser usually opens dev tools.

Comment: Homepage.aspx:96 
        
       Uncaught ReferenceError: updateGaugeValue is not defined
    at Homepage.aspx:96:1

Comment: Move your scripts to the HEAD tag then. I guess you have them at the end of BODY, right?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Still not works, but I am getting another error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'refresh')
    at updateGaugeValue (Homepage.aspx:25:20)
    at Homepage.aspx:176:1

Comment: The reason you were getting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'refresh')` is that you only have undefined var at the time the JS coming from C# is executed. The `window.gauge1` variable gets defined on "load" event (because you are defining an `onload` callback by assigning to `window.onload = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is much that we use a page onload/onready to setup, create and render the gauge.

But, we want a plain asp.net button, say maybe a text box, and then some code behind to set the value.

The issue is the on window load. If we "inject" a call to that routine, we can't (very well) control when our registry start up script runs as opposed to the existing code to setup + create the gauges.

So, what we need to do is "force" our startup script to wait. One great way is to use setTimeout, and that will in effect "push" our code to a routine on the JavaScript engine "execution stack" to wait, render page, run that gauge setup code, AND THEN run our desired code.

Worse yet? Testing this a bit, the event.prevent seems to mess this up.

So, here is a working proof of concept:

We put the script library code at top, for example:

```
<title></title>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.4/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/justgage/1.2.9/justgage.min.js"></script>
```

but, for OUR code, we want that stuff to be placed at bottom - after the DOM been created, setup and rendered.

So, now this code:

```
    <div style="padding:35px">

        <div style="border: solid 1px; float: left; padding: 8px">
            <legend>Client side buttons</legend>
            <button style="float: left" onclick="updateGaugeValue(4, event)">Click me</button>
            <button style="float: left; margin-left: 25px" onclick="updateGaugeValue2(6, event)">Click me</button>

        </div>

        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 30px; padding: 8px; border: solid 1px">
                <legend>Server side buttons</legend>

            <div style="float:left">
                Enter value 1-10 for gauage1:
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="50px">
                </asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdGauge1" runat="server"
                    Text="set guage 1"
                    CssClass="btn"
                    OnClick="cmdGauge1_Click" />
            </div>

            <div style="float: left; margin-left: 30px">
                Enter value 1-10 for gauage2:
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="50px">
                </asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdGauge2" runat="server"
                    Text="set guage 2"
                    CssClass="btn"
                    OnClick="cmdGauge2_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="clear: both; height: 50px">
        </div>

        <div id="gauge1" style="float:left;width:250px;"></div>

        <div id="gauge2" style="width:200px;float:left; margin-left:40px; width: 250px"></div>

    </div>


<script>
    var gauge1;
    var gauge2;


    window.onload = function () {

        gauge1 = new JustGage({
            id: "gauge1",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            title: "Files Uploaded",
            label: "Zip Files Uploaded",
            showInnerShadow: true,
            shadowOpacity: 2,
            shadowSize: 5,
            textRenderer: function () {
                return "144 / 400"
            }
        });

        gauge2 = new JustGage({
            id: "gauge2",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            title: "My Gauge",
            label: "Pdf Files uploaded",
            showInnerShadow: true,
            shadowOpacity: 2,
            shadowSize: 5,

        });
    };

    function updateGaugeValue(newValue, event) {
        // event.preventDefault();
        // alert('START')
        gauge1.refresh(newValue);
    }
    function updateGaugeValue2(newValue, event) {
        // event.preventDefault();
        gauge2.refresh(newValue);
    }


</script>
```

So, we wrapped our startup script in a timeout function. Even with a delay of "1", it works, since timeout pushed our code to the Java engine program stack, and thus it runs after everything else on that page.

code behind:

```
    protected void cmdGauge1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string jscode =
            $@"updateGaugeValue({TextBox1.Text},event)";

        jscode = "setTimeout(function () {" + jscode + "},1)"; 
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "myfunc", jscode, true);
    }

    protected void cmdGauge2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

and result:

[image]

However, there really not much need to "call" that existing JS routine you have, since the JS object exists (or we assume it will).

So, then this code :

```
    protected void cmdGauge1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string jscode =
            $@"gauge1.refresh({TextBox1.Text})";

        jscode = "setTimeout(function () {" + jscode + "},1)"; 
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "myfunc", jscode, true);
    }
```

So, now we don't even call that JS routine, but use the refresh method of the graph object.

So, now, we can put back (un-comment) out the `event.preventDefault()`, and thus both client side, and server side buttons in above example will now both work.

I should also point out that I used a delay of 1 (1 millisecond). This delay (amount) is not really required, but the FORCE of the routine to be pushed onto the Java engine execution stack is the important part here.

Comment: I have one more question related to problem... when I call ClientScript from function which takes 6 second, the gauge value change on my webpage after whole function is done, instead I call it on start on my function, any suggestion?

Comment: Order of code behind tends to not matter. On post-back, the WHOLE web page is up on the server. You can in code behind change controls, or whatever, but until the FULL post-back is 100% complete, the web page does not travel back to the client side. So, if something takes 6 seconds, then the whole page is still up on the server. Code behind to change a control, register a script or whatever? You not see any of those cumulative changes until the post-back is 100% completed as web page is up on the server being changed by code behind - only after all changes does page travel to client.

Comment: Its not clear if parts of that code can be broken up - but if that code takes 6 seconds, then you going to wait 6 seconds then, right? Not really 100% sure what you are asking here? You could perhaps have page render, and "then" call the code to set/load the value of the gauge. That being the case, probably a ajax call to a web method could be considered.

Comment: I am doing web pages which tests speed of databases query... So when I click on button and start the function, there is a for loop which executes some number of queries, this function includes timer and I want to refresh value of gauge after every query is executed, it is somehow possible?

Comment: Sure you can, but that will require some type of client side timer and refresh approach. You can't have a "time delay" on the server side for such updates, since as noted you MUST grasp the concept of a round trip.  So, either drop in a timer control, or even some client side JavaScript code + web method calls can do this. To grasp "why" you can't use delay server side, read this recent answer of mine:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75878021/how-c-sharp-toggles-div-styles-with-button-clicks/75878724#75878724

Comment: This answer contains references to a "Java engine", but I wonder if "JavaScript engine" was meant (i.e. the JS interpreter in a browser).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from moving your scripts to the HEAD tag instead of having them at the end of BODY, you might want to delay the execution of the code coming from C# after the loading is done.

Something like:

```
window.onload = () => { const event = new Event("dummy"); setTimeout(() => { updateGaugeValue(5, event) }, 0) };
```

Put that in the `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(...` call.

What it does:

```
// appending to the queue of onload functions ensures any other variables and functions, that were declared in main template's scripts, will be defined already.
window.onload = () => {
  const event = new Event("dummy"); // We want some event so that we can call .preventDefault() upon something.
  // There are better ways around it though.

  setTimeout(() => { 
    updateGaugeValue(5, event) 
  }, 0); // setting timeout to 0 effectively means, execute immediately after next round of UI updates
};
```

Comment: I am little confused now. This whole block of code should I put into `RegisterStartupScript` function as script parameter?

Comment: Yes. The RegisterStartupScript method produces a SCRIPT tag and inserts the contents in parameter inside. So you can write quite long scripts in it.

Comment: So If I call this :             `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "window.onload = () => { const event = new Event(\"dummy\"); setTimeout(() => { updateGaugeValue(5, event) }, 0) };", true);` there are 2 possibilities : 1. having JS code at the bottom - there isn't any error, but nothing changes 2. put JS code into head tag - when this function is called, I am geting again error cannot read properties and all my gauges dissapear from my webpage

Comment: And function still looks like this :         `function updateGaugeValue(newValue, event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            gauge1.refresh(newValue);
        }`

Comment: Remove the onload and just call it from bottom of body